# Agregar asterisco a inputs requeridos

Tags: javascript, html, css

Existe alguna forma de agregar con css un asterisco a los labels solo si el input tiene el atributo **required**?
Por ejemplo:
Tengo un div que contiene este label y este input

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Nombre</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" required >
    </div>
</div>
```

Todo esto es sin agregar ninguna clase ni al label ni al input, solo usar los atributos.

Probé trabajando con pseudoclases de css pero no funciona
Algo como esto:

```
form input:required {
   content:"*";
}
```

Funciona agregandolo en el input y lo que quiero es agregarlo en el label

Comment: `label:before{  content: "*"; }` no te sirve?

Comment: Quizas esta respuesta te puede servir https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197803/10755706

Comment: ¿Solo aplicarlo cuando el input es required?

Comment: Asi es solo cuando el campo es required

Comment: ¿Se puede emplear Js o solamente con CSS?

Comment: No es algo que puedas lograr solamente con CSS teniendo cuenta la estructura actual del HTML que compartes como ejemplo, en este caso es requerido el uso de javascript.

Comment: Sí con js seria util tambien pero no estoy seguro como implementar js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hice un ejemplo con solo CSS, no es el mejor ejemplo pero funciona correctamente.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>
 .form-group input:required~label::before {
  content: "* ";
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
</style>

<body>

 <div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card bg-light">
     <div class="card-body">
      <div class="form-group d-flex flex-row-reverse">
       <input type="text" class="col-sm-9 form-control" required>
       <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Nombre</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group d-flex flex-row-reverse">
       <input type="text" class="col-sm-9 form-control">
       <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Alias</label>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear una clase helper `.is-required`.

```css
.is-required:after {
  content: '*';
  margin-left: 3px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label is-required">Nombre</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" required >
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido esto, recorriendo los inputs existentes en el DOM y comprobando su atributo, si este es required hago visible el span que contiene el "*".
Por parte del html tengo dos inputs uno con el atributo "requiered" y otro que no lo tiene:

```
<label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
<input type="text" name="nombre" required>
<span id="asterisco" style="display: none;">*</span><br>
<label for="nombre">Apellido:</label>
<input type="text" name="apellido">
```

El código Javascript es el siguiente:

```
<script>
   var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       if(elements[i].required == true) {
           document.getElementById("asterisco").style.display = "inline";
       }
   }
</script>
```

Espero te sirva.